# EF7: "The EntityFramework package is not installed" when it is

Tags: entity-framework-core

Have already entered `Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands –Pre`, but when I try `Add-Migration Initial` I get the following error:

`The EntityFramework package is not installed on project '…'.`

As another clue, when I try the `Use-DbContext` command, I also get an error.  Here's my Package Manager Console session:

`PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands –Pre
Package 'EntityFramework.Commands.7.0.0-rc1-final' already exists in project '…'
PM> Add-Migration Initial
The EntityFramework package is not installed on project '…'.
PM> Use-DbContext
Use-DbContext : The term 'Use-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Use-DbContext
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Use-DbContext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am very new to asp.net 5 and EF7, but can you check if you have these dependency `dnx-clr-win-x86` or `dnx-clr-win-x64` installed?

Comment: I am not using asp.net.  Just EF7.  I followed the tutorial at http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/full-dotnet/new-db.html, and that worked.  And then I applied those instructions to an existing C# solution: added a project, installed the EF7 packages, and created a DbContext class.

Comment: Any luck with resolving this issue? I've got exactly the same (csproj with 4.5.2 .net and EF7 usage through "Package Manager Console")

Comment: The issue was that another project in the solution was using EF6, and EF6 was taking priority in the Nuget console.

Comment: I believe I've got the same EF6/EF7 mixed projects issue—error `The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'Service'`, where it was
 working before a wholesale package removal and reinstall—what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: Oops... never mind... I didn't have the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package installed. All is well.

Comment: I just had this problem. I had the proper packages installed and it was fixed by closing Visual Studio and reopening it.